# Two constructors, which is default?

Tags: c++

Okay I got a pretty simple assignment.

I got these two constructors for class Person:

```
Person( const string &, const string &, const string & );
Person( const string &, const string &, const string &,
const string & );
```

which of these are going to be the default constructor? is it always the one with most arguments or how does it work?